# How to use FastAPI request state variable AND also body parameter when using fastapi-cache?

Tags: python, fastapi

I have a FastAPI POST endpoint which receives a parameter in the request body. A global FastAPI Depends sets a Request state value which I want to retrieve in my method.

The following works fine:

```
from pydantic import BaseModel
from fastapi import APIRouter, Request


class MyPydanticValue(BaseModel):
    # some properties here


router = APIRouter()

@router.post(
  "/foo"
)
def perform_action(
  my_val: MyPydanticValue
  request: Request
):
  # do something with my_val
  ...

  # and also reference a state value that was set globally elsewhere
  print(request.state.x_some_value)
```

FastAPI sees the `my_val` parameter, recognises that it is a Pedantic model and therefore parses it from the request body.

I now want to cache the function, so I use [fastapi-cache](https://github.com/long2ice/fastapi-cache):

```
@router.post(
  "/foo"
)
@cache(expire=300)
def perform_action(
  my_val: MyPydanticValue
  request: Request
):
  # do something with my_val
  ...

  #and also reference a state value that was set globally elsewhere
  print(request.state.x_some_value)
```

Now I get an exception:

```
TypeError: perform_action() got multiple values for argument 'my_val'
```

The [fastapi-cache documentation](https://github.com/long2ice/fastapi-cache#injected-request-and-response-dependencies) states:

> The cache decorator injects dependencies for the Request and Response objects, so that it can add cache control headers to the outgoing response, and return a 304 Not Modified response when the incoming request has a matching If-Non-Match header. This only happens if the decorated endpoint doesn't already list these dependencies already.

My reading of that is that the injection shouldn't happen because I declare a parameter referring to the Request already. I think that's what is happening in the source code for the `@cache` decorator: https://github.com/long2ice/fastapi-cache/blob/v0.2.1/fastapi_cache/decorator.py#L41-L46. However, I think that my function is indeed actually getting a request parameter being injected by fastapi-cache and then subsequently by FastAPI.

What am I doing wrong - is there a way of working around this? How do I access the state value in the endpoint function whilst also parsing the Pydantic model from the request body?

Comment: Have you tried `my_val: MyPydanticValue = Body(...)`?

Comment: I have to swap the order of the parameters around because `my_val: MyPydanticValue = Body(...)` is a named parameter and I then get a near identical error: `got multiple values for argument 'request'` (i.e. the first parameter is being messed up)

Comment: I've encountered this exact same issue. I suspect there might be an error with the library

Comment: Yes @George, I found the bug: https://github.com/long2ice/fastapi-cache/issues/183#issuecomment-1563251789 The POST request has an erroneous extra variable but in any case the library is opinionated and doesn’t cache non-GET requests. The bug is removed in main latest but POST is still not cached so I opened this PR https://github.com/long2ice/fastapi-cache/pull/186